# Camel: disable polling messages

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am using Camel to setup some routing using the file and jms-queue components. The problem that I am having is that I cannot disable polling messages sent to the console.

I tryed multiple ways to disable these messages by setting the logging level(runLoggingLevel = OFF) on the routes, trace = false on the context, set a logger on the routes and a few others but nothing works.

A message from the file component looks like this:

```
2013-08-26 09:34:47,651 DEBUG [Camel (camelContextOrder) thread #0 - file://order-import/order-in] o.a.c.c.f.FileConsumer Took 0.001 seconds to poll: order-import\order-in
```

And a messsage from the jms queue:

```
2013-08-26 09:34:46,281 DEBUG [ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worker] o.a.a.s.k.MessageDatabase Checkpoint started.

2013-08-26 09:34:46,403 DEBUG [ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worker] o.a.a.s.k.MessageDatabase Checkpoint done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have DEBUG logging level configured. You should change that to INFO etc so Camel / ActiveMQ will not log so much.

Check your logging configuration to adjust this.